# What is the place in type hierarchy of nullable types?

Tags: generics, inheritance, nullable, kotlin

You can inherit type `A` from type `B`, but whenever you define type `A` you will get type `A?` (nullable on) for free. But where does it lie exactly in type hierarchy? `A?` inherits from `A` or other way around?

I ask this because I am puzzled with such code:

```
open class Foo {
  fun foo() : Int {
    return 0;
  }
}

fun test<T : Foo?>(x:T) : Int {
  return x.foo() // (@)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println(test<Foo?>(null))
}
```

I don't understand why line (@) is compiled? Or in other words I don't understand nullable types hierarchy then, because until now I though of `T` as `Foo?` or any type derived from it. Can you derive non-nullable type from nullable one and what it would mean then?

Sorry if this is something obvious, I am just learning Kotlin.

*(@) for nullable types it should be `x!!.foo()`.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the compiler. You should not be able to call a member of a `T` when `T` has a nullable upper bound. `X?` is a supertype of `X`.